# Pivot Table - De-nesting Columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I need to do a simple thing on a Excel Pivot Table, but I can't see how to do this.

I have a Pivot Table where the lines are a list of activities, the columns are months and the values are the number of days taken for each activities on each month. I want to add a new column with the "goal value" in days to each activity. I have the column with these goals, but If I try to add it to the table, it will get nested under the months...

So, how can I add this column without nesting it?

Example:

I have this Table:

[image]

I want to add this collumn without nesting it:

[image]

Comment: This question is not about any aspect of programming or formulas. It should be moved to Superuser.com

Comment: Sorry... didn't knew that. Live and learning

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to learn about what is on topic here and what is not.